# Most efficient way to get count from table based on time frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `clicks` table which logs clicks on links on the site.

In the `links` table I want a field `weekly_clicks` that would update via a cron job.

How can I write the following pseudocode query in Ruby/ActiveRecord?

```
Select count(clicks) FROM clicks
  WHERE link_id=xxx
  AND created_at within previous 7 days including today
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Click.where(:link_id => 'xxx').where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
link = Link.new(params)
link.weekly_clicks = Click.where("created_at > ? and link_id = ?", 1.week.ago, xxx).count
link.save
```